# How to access controls cross Outlook 2013 addins

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

How to get selected value of ComboBox from another Add-in( existing add-in's control ) from my new add-in (Outlook 2013).

Answer (score 1):

The Fluent UI doesn't provide anything for that. I'd suggest contacting the other add-in developers to provide a public method which you may call. See [Call code in VSTO Add-ins from other Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions) for more information.

Comment: Just want to get value something  like Font Name in the Font ComboBox in Message Tab

Comment: The font ComboBox depends on the current selection, you can get that information from `Application.Selection.Range`.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. Yes Fluent UI doesn't support. But Microsoft provide another lib that can access all text that is shown on screen in order for access from Accessibility application. See detail [Accessiblity Code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSOfficeRibbonAccessibility-cd7fe67f/sourcecode?fileId=22031&pathId=1828933857)